# Run h2o.ai as a service (background)

Tags: python, h2o

How to run H2O.ai python in background?

I tried putting

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
input() # to stop closing the python program
```

in a python script and run with `nohup python3 script.py &`. But the script exits if I enter the return key. Is there a way to avoid this behavior and run h2o.ai in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python session is ending, and thus your H2O cluster may be stopping.

You can start H2O 3 from [Command Line](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html#from-the-command-line), for example:

```
java -jar h2o.jar
```

^you will need to be in the directory of your H2O 3 folder (like [here](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zizler/1/index.html)).

Alternatively, you can add `sleep` to your script:

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

^this will leave the program running for 10 seconds. If you want to extend it, just add more seconds to the max time you want the program to run.

Comment: Java version of h2o doesn't support every algorithm. Does it?

Comment: @RumeshMadhusanka Java "version" has everything. In fact H2O is written in Java, and both R and Python APIs are just thin clients around calls to the Java server. When you do `h2o.init()` it starts the Java server running, if it is isn't already.